Kvm GPU passthrough Debian 12
I have a Debian 12 in a machine where I have installed Windows 10 as a Guest using KVM (Managed with Virt-Manager).
The machine has 2 graphic cards.

GeForce RTX 2060 12GB (I want to use in the host)
AMD Radeon R5 220 2GB ddr3 (I wanted to use in a Guest Windows 10)

I follow mainly this link kvm-gpu-passthrough
In the Windows the device manager shows the Amd Radeon graphic cards and the Red Hat QXL controller. In the Windows I have install the driver from AMD driver r5-220 but when I try to run the AMD program it says "No AMD graphics driver is installed or the AMD driver is not functioning properly
I have configured the /etc/default/grub file as
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet modprobe.blacklist=radeon"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="amd_iommu=on iommu=pt "

Using the Virt-Manager I have added 2 PCI associated to the AMD card
<controller type="pci" index="16" model="pcie-to-pci-bridge">
  <model name="pcie-pci-bridge"/>
  <alias name="pci.16"/>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x01" slot="0x00" function="0x0"/>
</controller>

and
<controller type="pci" index="0" model="pcie-root">
  <alias name="pcie.0"/>
</controller>

I have used the script
!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for g in /sys/kernel/iommu_groups/*; do
    echo "IOMMU Group ${g##*/}:"
    for d in $g/devices/*; do
        echo -e "\t$(lspci -nns ${d##*/})"
    done;
done;


in order to get this 2 "pci devices". This script gives me
IOMMU Group 28:
    0b:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 [GeForce RTX 2060 12GB] [10de:1f03] (rev a1)
    0b:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:10f9] (rev a1)
IOMMU Group 29:
    0c:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series] [1002:68f9]
    0c:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 5400/6300/7300 Series] [1002:aa68]


and I have supposed that the Group 29 is the one I have to add to the Virtual Machine
I do not know if I am missing something.
